# How to add product to wishlist after login by guest customer?

Tags: magento-1, products, controllers, ajax, wishlist

Add to wishlist is being done in AJAX for online customers and the products are successfully added in wishlist. For offline/guests, if they click add to wishlist a pop-up is shown with link to login. The link re-directs customer to login/create an account page. Once they login the page is re-directed to My account dashboard. The product is not added to wishlist. How can this be resolved. How to keep AJAX functionality as well as basic magento functionality to add the product to wishlist directly after the customer creates an account/ logs into their account. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php class Excellence_AjaxWishlist_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function compareAction(){
        $response = array();

        if ($productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product')) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);

            if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('The product %s has been added to comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
                $this->loadLayout();
                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.compare.sidebar');
                $sidebar_block->setTemplate('ajaxwishlist/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml');
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }



    protected function _getWishlist()
    {
        $wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
        if ($wishlist) {
            return $wishlist;
        }

        try {
            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')
            ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer(), true);
            Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addException($e,
            Mage::helper('wishlist')->__('Cannot create wishlist.')
            );
            return false;
        }

        return $wishlist;
    }
    public function addAction()
    {

        $response = array();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('wishlist/general/active')) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Wishlist Has Been Disabled By Admin');
        }
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Please Login First');
        }

        if(empty($response)){
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
            if (!$wishlist) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to Create Wishlist');
            }else{

                $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
                if (!$productId) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Product Not Found');
                     }else{

                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                    if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                        $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot specify product.');
                    }else{

                        try {
                            $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($requestParams);

                            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
                            if (is_string($result)) {
                                Mage::throwException($result);
                            }
                            $wishlist->save();

                            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                                'wishlist_add_product',
                            array(
                                'wishlist'  => $wishlist,
                                'product'   => $product,
                                'item'      => $result
                            )
                            );

                            Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

                            $message = $this->__('%1$s has been added to your wishlist.', $product->getName(), $referer);
                            $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                            $response['message'] = $message;

                            Mage::unregister('wishlist');

                            $this->loadLayout();
                            $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                            $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wishlist_sidebar');
                            $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                            $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                            $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                        }
                        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage());
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e) {
                            mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code done for ajax

Comment: @MTM I have posted the code of my index controller in the question. Pl refer.